# Print to console in JAVA

Tags: java, file, console

I have a simple question. My program asks the user to type a name, range, and length to generate random numbers. The result will be printed into a file from the console. I want to know is it possible to print to the console that the file has been printed when it's done.

Currently this is my set up to print to a file:

````
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Choose a name to your file: ");
        String fn = s.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Choose your range: ");
        String rn = s.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Choose your length of array: ");
        String ln = s.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        
        int rangeToInt = Integer.parseInt(rn);
        int lengthToInt = Integer.parseInt(ln);
        
        File file = new File(fn +".txt");
        PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(file);
        //System.out.println("File Has been Printed");
        System.setOut(stream);
        
    
        
        int[] result = getRandomNumbersWithNoDuplicates(rangeToInt, lengthToInt);
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            Arrays.sort(result);
            System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("Current Time in Millieseconds = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("\nNumber of element in the array are: " + result.length + "\n");
        
    
    }// end of main
     ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `System.setOut`. When you do that, you can no longer print to the console. Instead of `System.out.println` to write to the file, just... `stream.println` to write to the file. Then you can use `System.out` to print to the console.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to follow your recommendation to fix my issue!